# Convert date-time into Julian day format

Tags: r

I have a column of Date.time in the format `2010-10-06 10:30`. I would like to convert this into Julian day format, with decimal points. It would be great if it is possible to set the origin time as `2008-01-01 00:00`.

The column of Date.Time consists of date starting from `2008-01-01 00:00` to `2013-12-31 11:00`. Hence I have to convert the whole column with the first date as `1.something`.

How do I make this conversion in R?

Comment: This example is not helpful for me.

Comment: yes i did.
it returns with `NA`

Comment: with capital M in `%H:%m` it does. Thank you. @akrun could you please check out my edited question as I have to convert a whole column starting from `2008-01-01 00:00`.

Comment: It is doing but with the change in year it is changing the `yday` as well. 
The first day is coming as `1` but as my year changes from  `2008 to 2009` it is again restarting the numbers from `1`. Can I have my `2009-01-01` as `367.something` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question, this is a simple `difftime` operation:

```
x <- c("2008-01-01 00:00", "2013-12-31 11:00")
difftime(as.POSIXct(x), "2008-01-01", units="days")
#Time differences in days
#[1]    0.000 2191.458
```

Comment: I want to convert each day(along with its given time) and make a separate column of it.

Comment: ...and? `data$newcolumn <- difftime(as.POSIXct(data$Date.Time), "2008-01-01", units="days")` or something like that will sort it out.